# 4K Laptop running Windows 10 Hyper-v Ubuntu 16.04 VM

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop on to Hyper-V Gen. 2 VM.

Is there any way to go above 1920 x 1080 resolution ?

I would like to full screen on 4K laptop.